# why are these memoised functions different?

Tags: r, memoization, memoise

I see that if I use memoise on a function in two different ways, I get two different behaviours, and I'd like to understand why.

```
# Non Memoised function
fib <- function(n) {
  if (n < 2) return(1)
  fib(n - 2) + fib(n - 1)
}

system.time(fib(23))
system.time(fib(24))

library(memoise)

# Memoisation stragagy 1
fib_fast <- memoise(function(n) {
  if (n < 2) return(1)
  fib_fast(n - 2) + fib_fast(n - 1)
})

system.time(fib_fast(23))
system.time(fib_fast(24))

# Memoisation strategy 2
fib_not_as_fast <- memoise(fib)

system.time(fib_not_as_fast(23))
system.time(fib_not_as_fast(24))
```

Strategy 1, is really fast, as it reuses the recursive results, whereas stratagy 2 is only fast if the exact input has been seen before.

Can someone explain to me why this is?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I think that the reason is simple. In the slow case, the function `fib_not_as_fast` is memoised. Inside the function, `fib` is called, which is *not* memoised. To be more detailed: when you calculate `fib_not_so_fast(24)`, inside the function you have `fib(22) + fib(23)`. Both of these have not been memoised.

In `fib_fast`, however, you use the memoised version also in the recursion. So, in this case, `fib_fast(24)` needs to evaluate `fib_fast(22) + fib_fast(23)`. Both these function calls have already happened, when you calculated `fib_fast(23)` and are thus memoised.

What does work is to memoise a function later, after it has been defined. So, simply redefining the function `fib()` as  `fib <- memoise(fib)` will work.

Comment: Followup: Suppose you have `fib` already defined -- how would you memoise it? Substitute stuff in the body of the function?

Comment: @Frank - `Recall` is useful for avoiding those situations.  If you write recursive functions in R then you should use `Recall`

Comment: @Dason Ah cool, didn't know there was such a function. Looks like the memoise package is not set up to deal with that case if I understand correctly. I'm seeing the same timings for `fib <- function(n) {if (n < 2) return(1); Recall(n - 2) + Recall(n - 1)}` and for `ffib <- memoise(fib)`

Comment: Is this because the internal fibs have been evaluated already? I understand that the internal fibs are not memoized, but I am struggling to understand why they are not?

Comment: The memoised version of `fib` is stored `fib_not_so_fast`. `fib` itself is never stored as a memoised function.